# Cannot read property of null in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am develop an app in Ionic 3, I have a component named profile that have information about the user logged from firebase, this component are on tabs, work perfectly in the first tab, but when I change the tab, give me an error, cannot read property 'profileData' of null. Why in the first tab work correctly and the second or third not?

I am try the safety operator ? but doesn't work.

My code is:

profile.html

```html
<div>
  <ion-item no-lines class="user" *ngFor="let data of profileData">
    <img class="user-img" src="../../assets/imgs/logo.png" />
    <h4>Nombre: {{ data.name }}</h4>
    <h4>Siguiendo: {{ data.followQuantity }}</h4>
    <h4>Puntos: {{ data.points }}</h4>
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

profile.ts

```js
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from 
'@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 
'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'profile',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})
export class ProfileComponent {

 profileRef: AngularFireList<any>;
 profileData: any;


 constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase, private 
   cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
   console.log("Constructor")
   var ref = firebase.database().ref('/users/');
   ref.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      if(child.val().UID == firebase.auth().currentUser.uid){
        console.log("Usuario logueado")
        console.log(snapshot)
        this.profileData = [{
          name: child.val().name,
          lastname: child.val().lastname,
          phone: child.val().phone,
          direction: child.val().direction,
          followQuantity: child.val().followQuantity,
          points: child.val().points,
          sex: child.val().sex,
        }];
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      }
      });
  })
}

}
```

The error: 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'profileData' of null

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you need to call **off()** to unsubscribe from getting data from database **when your profile component is being removed**. To do that you need to use **ngOnDestroy()** angular's lifecycle hook. Code example:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef } from 
'@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 
'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
  selector: 'profile',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})
export class ProfileComponent {

 profileRef: AngularFireList<any>;
 profileData: any;
 ref: any;


 constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {
   console.log("Constructor")
   this.ref = firebase.database().ref('/users/');
   this.ref.on('value', this.onUsersFetch.bind(this));
 }

 private onUsersFetch(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      if(child.val().UID == firebase.auth().currentUser.uid){
        console.log("Usuario logueado")
        console.log(snapshot)
        this.profileData = [{
          name: child.val().name,
          lastname: child.val().lastname,
          phone: child.val().phone,
          direction: child.val().direction,
          followQuantity: child.val().followQuantity,
          points: child.val().points,
          sex: child.val().sex,
        }];
        this.cdRef.detectChanges();
      }
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
      this.ref.off('value', this.onUsersFetch.bind(this));
  }

}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, every page of every tab have a profile component

Comment: I see that, on destroy no it's called never